# What is burst in Uniprocessor scheduling?

Tags: process, operating-system, scheduling

What is "burst" in Uniprocessor scheduling? I still do not quite understand it, and is this a general term that can be applicable to any uniprocessor scheduling algorithm?

Comment: I don't understand it either. Almost every app I've ever developed has a 'burst time' that is undefined, for the purposes of scheduling anyway, since the instantaneous CPU used depends upon the loading from local users, peripherals networked peers and the process is designed to run forever.  None of these 'burst time', 'arrival time' etc. questions make any kind of sense to me.  They smell of jurassic batch processing:(

Comment: 'uniprocessor scheduling algorithm?' see - name a uniprocessor environment today....

Comment: Burst time is the time required by the process to complete execution. It is also called running time or execution time.